# React hook re-renders component only when another parameter gets passed

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created my own react component called `useSetting` to be a wrapper around the [dexie.js](https://dexie.org/) library (better for my use-case to use an own hook) for the indexed db. This one goes as the following:

```
export const useSetting = (id: string, key: string, trigger_function?: Function): [any, Function] => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();
    const changeStatus = (value: any) => widgetsDb.setSetting(id, key, value);

    useEvent(`widget.${id}.${key}`, HashCode.value(id + key + String(trigger_function)), null, (data: any) => {
        const value = (trigger_function || (() => {}))(data) || data;        
        setState(value);
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        widgetsDb.getSetting(id, key).then((data: any) => {
            const value = (trigger_function || (() => {}))(data) || data;
            setState(value);
        })
    }, [id, key, trigger_function])
    
    return [state, changeStatus];
}
```

and the problem is that the hook does not re-render the component if the value changed **and no trigger_function was passed**. To better explain this scenario see this code snippet:

```
const [ position, setPosition ] = useSetting(props.id, "position");
```

here, useSetting does not re-render the component whenever the state in the `useSetting` hook changes. But when I pass a function to the `trigger_function` field:

```
const [ position, setPosition ] = useSetting(props.id, "position", () => {});
```

suddenly, the component starts to rerender when the state changes. That's what really confuses me.

To give more context:

- `widgetsDb.getSetting` does set the initial value in useEffect
- `useEvent` does indeed execute the arrow function no matter if I pass trigger_function or not
- `state` always gets updated in the `useSetting` hook whenever the arrow function in `useEvent` gets executed
- The component which uses `useEvent` is rendered from a list meaning that I have a list of components being rendered. Those are then passed into another component:

App.tsx:

```
<div className="App">
    <Background>
    {componentsList.map((component: Component) => {                 
        if (component.element === null) {
            return null;
        }
                    
        return <component.element id={component.fullId} key={component.fullId} />;
    })}

    <SettingsComponent />
    </Background>
</div>
```

Background.tsx:

```
<div>
  {props.children.map(child => React.cloneElement(child, {blur}))}
</div>
```

I have been working on this problem now for a long time and couldn't figure out anything. Unfortunately, even "similar" cases on SO or elsewhere didn't help me any further.
Hope that anyone can help me out here or point me in the right direction. I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: What is useEvent in your code ?

Comment: @Axnyff See here https://haste.pinofett.de/fh4q592d7f.coffeescript The method totally works fine and if I set the state in the component itself by using useEvent, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things you need to take into account:

- Components in React are rendered based on the values and logic in the JSX. Since `state` is not used in your JSX, React does not get any trigger to re-render.
- Be wary that javascript does not support changes on objects, so if you make `state` to be an object, React won't know if a property within it changes. This is different when using React's own `setState` (in class-based components), but I don't think it'll work if you simulate that in a React hook.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As to the first point, I thought returning the state variable should be enough? I actually use the `position` variable in my code, see here: https://haste.pinofett.de/hy0w3gq439.typescript As for the second one: State won't be an object but thanks for the reminder. I actually know about this. But this still doesn't explain the weirdness with the `trigger_function` parameter

Comment: @Ari24 Ok, so I see `position` is used in that external example you provide, but not in the question. Either way, this is a pre-computed value (a string, using the result of `positionValues`, not the reactive property itself. React won't eh.. react to that if it changes. At least not in the way you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I actually got a work-around somewhat working including another hook from the dexie library itself. It's not the best solution but it works for my case and is actually a lot simpler. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: No problem. Another workaround I'm thinking of (but this might work only in class-based components) is [`this.forceUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate), but do ask yourself whether your approach to this whole thing is the right one. If it's a style you want updated, perhaps it's better to just write a (`get`) function that returns the dynamic classname.